# Callback as an option in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am working with node.js and how can I set callback as an option of a specific function?

For example:

```
    function sum(a, b, callback) {
      return callback(a+b)
    }

    var result = sum(a,b) // this seems to cause error: callback is not a function

    sum(a, b, function(sum) {
      // this works fine
    })
```

Is there any way to make both of the above (with and without callback) work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply check that the `callback` argument is a function.

```
if(typeof callback === 'function'){
    return callback(a+b);
}
```

Thus, your sum function can be written as :

```
function sum(a, b, callback) {
    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        return callback(a+b)
    }
    else {
      return a+b;
    }
}
```

([Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cv50hmgv/))

Comment: Thanks! I thought I have to overload this function or something... Being influenced  by C++ too much

Answer (score -2):

Hi you can have your code as below

```
function sum(a, b, callback) {
    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        return callback(a+b)
    }
    else {
      return a+b;
    }
}
```

which is also mentioned in the above post